# What is this notation doing? .()

Tags: r

I came across this in my code, and I'm wondering what this is doing. It's getting a count of records of some sort, I think.

What does the notation `.()` do, and where can I read more about it?

`data_frame[, .N, keyby = .(FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4)][N>1]`

Comment: `.()` is an alias of `list()` when using the `data.table` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html See section 1 d.